# Best SQL query for list of records containing certain characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm working with a relatively large SQL Server 2000 DB at the moment. It's 80 GB in size, and have millions and millions of records.

I currently need to return a list of names that contains at least one of a series of illegal characters. By illegal characters is just meant an arbitrary list of characters that is defined by the customer. In the below example I use question mark, semi-colon, period and comma as the illegal character list.

I was initially thinking to do a CLR function that worked with regular expressions, but as it's SQL server 2000, I guess that's out of the question.

At the moment I've done like this:

```
select x from users
where 
columnToBeSearched like '%?%' OR
columnToBeSearched like '%;%' OR
columnToBeSearched like '%.%' OR
columnToBeSearched like '%,%' OR
otherColumnToBeSearched like '%?%' OR
otherColumnToBeSearched like '%;%' OR
otherColumnToBeSearched like '%.%' OR
otherColumnToBeSearched like '%,%'
```

Now, I'm not a SQL expert by any means, but I get the feeling that the above query will be very inefficient. Doing 8 multiple wildcard searches in a table with millions of records, seems like it could slow the system down rather seriously. While it seems to work fine on test servers, I am getting the "this has to be completely wrong" vibe.

As I need to execute this script on a live production server eventually, I hope to achieve good performance, so as not to clog the system. The script might need to be expanded later on to include more illegal characters, but this is very unlikely.

To sum up: My aim is to get a list of records where either of two columns contain a customer-defined "illegal character". The database is live and massive, so I want a somewhat efficient approach, as I believe the above queries will be very slow.

Can anyone tell me the best way for achieving my result? Thanks!

/Morten

Comment: Do you need to run the query only once? Or is this something you will need to do repeatedly?

Comment: I am not entirely sure actually. It will most likely be run a maximum of once pr. Week and might even be a one-off operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't get used much, but the `LIKE` statement accepts patterns in a similar (but much simplified) way to Regex. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) is the msdn page for it.

In your case you could simplify to (untested):

```
select x from users
where 
    columnToBeSearched like '%[?;.,]%' OR
    otherColumnToBeSearched like '%[?;.,]%'
```

Also note that you can create the `LIKE` pattern as a variable, allowing for the customer defined part of your requirements.

One other major optimization: If you've got an updated date (or timestamp) on the user row (for any audit history type of thing), then you can always just query rows updated since the last time you checked.

Comment: I just tried it - It returns the same amount of records as my previous query, so it works fine. However, my original query took 34 seconds to execute, while this one took 37, so more or less the same. I'm unsure though, if I can even measure the efficiency of the query, in the amount of seconds it takes to execute?

Comment: One major optimization: If you've got an updated date on the user row (for any audit history type of thing), then you can always just query rows updated since the last time you checked. (Updated into Answer text)

Comment: You may also want to see if you get a gain from `... colname collate Latin1_General_Bin like '%[?;.,]%'`

Comment: Alex: Just tried it, and it doesn't seem to influence the performance. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: Jon, about your optimization tip: I have a CreatedDate datetime. I'm putting this query into a stored procedure. Is there anyway I can automatically store the last execution time for the stored procedure? This way I can use that as a parameter, without the DB admin having to remember when he last ran the query?

Comment: You'd need a table, either with a single row, or in the Key, Value style. Update that when you exec your proc. Be careful with a createdstamp - does this change if rows are updated (otherwise you'll miss where the two fields get bad data on updates).

Answer (score 3):

If this is a query that will be run repeatedly, you are probably better off creating an index for it. The syntax escapes me at the moment, but you could probably create a computed column (edit: probably a `PERSISTED` computed column) which is 1 if `columnToBeSearched` or `otherColumnToBeSearched` contain illegal characters, and 0 otherwise. Create an index on that column and simply select all rows where the column is 1. This assumes that the set of illegal characters is fixed for that database installation (I assume that that's what you mean by "specified by the customer"). If, on the other hand, each query might specify a different set of illegal characters, this won't work.

By the way, if you don't mind the risk of reading uncommitted rows, you can run the query in a transaction with the the isolation level `READ UNCOMMITTED`, so that you won't block other transactions.

Comment: Would a computed column not impact on the performance of every other operation on the table though?

Comment: @Jon Egerton: Only insert and update operations (if the computed column is `PERSISTED`) - but yes, that should definitely be taken into consideration. The performance hit shouldn't be very high, though.

Comment: Thanks Aasmund, I will recommend creating an index, depending on how often the query will need to be run.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to partition your data horizontally and "split" your query in a number of smaller queries. For instance you can do

```
SELECT x FROM users 
WHERE users.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 5000 
AND -- your filters on columnToBeSearched
```

putting your results back together in one list may be a little inconvenient, but if it's a report you're only extracting once (or once in a while) it may be feasible.
I'm assuming ID is the primary key of users or a column that has a index defined, which means SQL should be able to create an efficient execution plan, where it evaluates users.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 5000 (fast) before trying to check the filters (which may be slow).

Answer (score 0):

Look up PATINDEX it allows you to put in an array of characters PATINDEX('[._]',ColumnName) returns a 0 or a value of the first occurance of an illegal character found in a certain value. Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried it, but performance was a bit worse actually. But thanks anyway!